# $g_1≥g_2≥g_3>0,g_1≤g_2+g_3$; algorithm to find 3 complex number $z_1,z_2,z_3$: $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1,z_1g_1+z_2g_2+z_3g_3=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, algorithms

There are 3 positive numbers $g_1≥g_2≥g_3>0$, also, $g_1≤g_2+g_3$. What algotithm you think that can find 3 complex number $z_1,z_2,z_3$ such that $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$ and $z_1g_1+z_2g_2+z_3g_3=0$?

For me, $g_1≤g_2+g_3$, so $-z_1g_1=z_2g_2+z_3g_3$. However, $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$, $z_1$ can not larger then $z_2+z_3$ and $g_1$ also can not larger than $g_2+g_3$. I don't think that have a nice solution.

Comment: This problem is exactly equivalent to the problem of finding a triangle with sides $g_1$, $g_2$, $g_3$ — can you see why? If you imagine a 'ruler and compass' solution to the problem that might help to understand how to do it algebraically. (Another way of thinking about it: once you have a solution you can obviously 'rotate' it by multiplying $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ by the same unit vector, so you might as well take $z_1=1$; that makes the algebra easier.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I think $z_ig_i$ can be a line, so there are 3 lines to make a triangle to make the sum of them is 0, right?

Comment: Exactly so. And the $g_i$ are the lengths of those sides.